# Cursor work only first iteraction in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help on a cursor in Microsoft SQL Server.

I have two tables. The first one stores data from employees (table `PFUNC`), and column `Chapa` identifies a person. In the other table, `ABATFUN`, I have the registry of the days the employees was at the company.

I was trying to write a cursor that checks for every day if the employee was at the company. The column `CHAPA` is the FK in the table `ABATFUN`.

In my code, I just limit the cursor to only 2 employees, using the exclusive identifier "chapa".

```
declare 
    @startDate DATE = '2020-03-01',
    @endDate DATE = '2020-03-31',
    @chapa varchar(10),
    @name varchar(50)

--declare the cursor. Here i get the registry for only 2 employees for test
declare cur_Chapas cursor for 
    select CHAPA, NOME  
    from PFUNC  
    where CODSITUACAO IN ('A', 'U','X','V') 
      and (CHAPA = 03304 or CHAPA = 03368)

open cur_Chapas

fetch next from cur_Chapas into @chapa, @name 

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    while (@StartDate <= @endDate)
    begin
        if exists (select * from ABATFUN where CHAPA  = @chapa and DATA = @startDate)
            print 'There are registry of the employer name: '+ @chapa +' '+ @name+ ' Day: ' + convert (varchar,@StartDate,4)
        else
            print 'There are not any registry of the employer name: '+ @chapa +' '+ @name+ ' Day: ' + convert (varchar,@StartDate,4)
        set @startDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @endDate)
    end

    fetch next from cur_Chapas into @chapa, @name
end

close cur_Chapas
deallocate cur_Chapas
```

The problem is, when I run this code, it show me data only for the first employee. The cursor doesn't go to the next iteration. What am I doing wrong?

What do I need to do to make the cursor bring me the data from the second employee ?

When I run only the cursor, without second "While" in the code, it brings me the data from "Chapa" and "Name": https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaqFU.png

Thanks and sorry for my bad English =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset `@startDate` every time through the outer loop.

```
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @startDate DATE = '2020-03-01'
    while (@StartDate <= @endDate)
    begin
        if exists (select * from ABATFUN where CHAPA  = @chapa and DATA = @startDate)
            print 'There are registry of the employer name: '+ @chapa +' '+ @name+ ' Day: ' + convert (varchar,@StartDate,4)
        else
            print 'There are not any registry of the employer name: '+ @chapa +' '+ @name+ ' Day: ' + convert (varchar,@StartDate,4)
        set @startDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @endDate)
    end

    fetch next from cur_Chapas into @chapa, @name
end
```

When you process the second result from the cursor `@startDate` is already equal to `@endDate` and the inner loop is not run.

Comment: Wow dude! I totally forgot about this detail, shame on my. This solve my problem, you rocks!!